# How do I add spacing between two subfigures?

Tags: beamer, floats

I have two subfigures and I cannot add spacing between them. I have followed the directions in the other posts

`\end{subfigure}\hfill%` but this does not seem to be working. How do I add spacing between my two subfigures?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{varwidth}
%\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{media9}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
%\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multimedia}
%\institute{Perimeter College, Dunwoody, G.A.}
\date{}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\AtBeginBibliography{\footnotesize}
\appto\bibsetup{\scriptsize}
\usepackage{physics}  
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\small}
\metroset{block=fill}



\begin{frame}[t,plain]{\Large{Math 2212: Supplemental Instruction}}


\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
    
\textbf{\large{Struggling with Calc 2?}}

        
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{2}^5 \frac{1}{\sqrt{5-x}} \dd{x} 
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\\\\
&\int_{0}^\frac{1}{2} \frac{\dd{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
&\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[x]{17}\\\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}
&\int_{1}^\infty\frac{\ln{x}}{x} \dd{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}  
\centering

\large{\textbf{\textit{S.I. SESSION'S ARE AVAILABLE}}}   \\
\small{  Course: \hfill MATH 2212\\}
\small{  Professor: \hfill Dr. Muiny\\}
\small{  Time: \hfill 9am - 10pm\\}
\small{  Location: \hfill Rm 33\\}\vspace{.5cm}
         
S.I. Session: \hfill Tue. 9am - 10pm\\
Q\&A Sesssion: \hfill Wed. 9am - 10pm\\
S.I. Session:\hfill Thur. 9am - 10pm\\

     
\end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}


\end{frame}






\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the reason for teh `subfigure` environments here? If you just use this to place contents side by side, why not use beamer's built-in column mechanism?

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.